# A few questions about elementary counting problems

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

These questions are so small I don't think they deserve separate threads. So, I'll just pile them all up here.

---

Problem: Four students are finalists in a contest in which ten questions are asked of the four students. Only the first student to answer a particular question correctly receives credit for that question. We are interested in the number of questions answered by each student. Assuming that every question is answered correctly by some student, how many outcomes are possible?

Solution: $\displaystyle{\binom{13}{10}}$.

My question: From the looks of it they distributed ten identical questions to four distinct students. But would it make sense to ask the same question ten times? Shouldn't the questions be distinct in which case the answer would be $4^{10}?$

---

Problem: Find the number of distinguishable ways to label a six-sided die
with the elements of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Solution: Label the top face with $1$. This breaks one of the symmetries on the faces of the cube. The remaining faces are labeled as follows:

- Choose one of the remaining numbers to place on the bottom face. There are $5$
  possibilities.
- Place one of the remaining numbers on the front face. This breaks the final
  symmetry.
- Label the right face. There are $3$ possibilities.
- Label the back face. There are $2$ possibilities.
- The final number is the forced on the left face. Thus by the Multiplication Principle, there are $5 ∗ 3 ∗ 2 = 30$ possibilities.

My question is about the second bullet. Shouldn't there be four possibilities?

---

The number of lattice paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, k)$ is $\displaystyle{\binom{n + k}{k}}$. That's easy to show because we simply count the number of $m$-words from the set $\{n, k\}$ where $n$ stands for "move East" and $k$ stands for "move North". Then to me it would be natural to generalize this problem from two coordinates to $l$ coordinates like so: $\displaystyle{\binom{n_1 + n_2 + \ldots + n_l}{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_{l - 1}}}$ by analogy with the two-coordinate case as we don't have to choose places for the last letter when constructing an $m$-word. But it turns out the actual generalization is  $\displaystyle{\binom{n_1 + n_2 + \ldots + n_l}{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_l}}$. Don't the $l - 1$ letters automatically determine the place/s for the last letter, say, $n_l$ in the $m$-word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "Only the first student to answer a particular question correctly receives credit for that question." This would be meaningless if each particular question only went to one student.
2. There are not four different possibilities because you can rotate the die around a vertical axis so the face you labelled is in any of four directions.
3. Note that in the case of dimension $2$, ${n+k \choose k} = \frac{(n+k)!}{n! k!}$ which in multinomial coefficient notation would be ${n+k \choose n, k}$.

Comment: In the first problem they distribute the questions to students without restrictions meaning, for example, a single student might end up answering all of the questions. But the given solution still implies all the questions are identical which makes no sense to me.

Comment: @user747743  What matters in that problem is how many of the questions each student asks correctly.